# C# Shorten Button Assigned to Reset Values

Tags: c#, wpf, visual-studio-2012

I've just started programming meaning I'm new... I've made a tic tac toe game using else if statements.

The code below is code that will reset certain values within my game, I'm sure there's but I can't find an answer - How do I shorten this block of code?

```
        btn1.Enabled = true;
        btn2.Enabled = true;
        btn3.Enabled = true;
        btn4.Enabled = true;
        btn5.Enabled = true;
        btn6.Enabled = true;
        btn7.Enabled = true;
        btn8.Enabled = true;
        btn9.Enabled = true;

        btn1.Text = "";
        btn2.Text = "";
        btn3.Text = "";
        btn4.Text = "";
        btn5.Text = "";
        btn6.Text = "";
        btn7.Text = "";
        btn8.Text = "";
        btn9.Text = "";

        btn1.BackColor = default(Color);
        btn2.BackColor = default(Color);
        btn3.BackColor = default(Color);
        btn4.BackColor = default(Color);
        btn5.BackColor = default(Color);
        btn6.BackColor = default(Color);
        btn7.BackColor = default(Color);
        btn8.BackColor = default(Color);
        btn9.BackColor = default(Color);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should use an **[array](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa288453%28v=vs.71%29.aspx)**, or better yet, a **[generic list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx)** which will hold all your buttons.

For example:

```
 List<Button> buttonList = new List<Button>();

 // Add buttons to list...
 buttonList.Add(btn1);
 buttonList.Add(btn2);
 ...
```

Then, you can iterate on the list like this:

```
foreach (Button btn in buttonList)
{
     btn.Text = "";
     btn.BackColor = default(Color);
}
```

The code above will run on all the buttons in the list and for each of them clear the text and set the BackColor.

Answer (score 1):

This should be done with arrays, instead of btn1, you would have btn[], and then you can access them with a for loop:

```
for (i=0; i<9; i++) {
btn[i].Enabled = true;
btn[i].Text = "";
btn[i].Color = default(Color);
}
```

and these 5 lines of code contain all the code you have above.

Answer (score 0):

reset for all button at control

```
foreach(var item in this.Controls)
{
    if (item is Button)
    {
        item.Enabled = true;
        item.Text = "";
        item.BackColor = default(Color);
    }
}
```